# Not found: Table seraphic-plexus-404015: (Bigquery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sqlcode

Why does the same code work sometimes and doesn't others? Is it because I am using sandbox?

Here is the code:

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `seraphic-plexus-404015.employee_data.departments `
```

[image: First Image]

I opened new query in a new tab and it didn't work, the FROM kept raising an error that the table can't be found
But i opened a query from the table when it was open and it worked
Here is the code:

```sql
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  `seraphic-plexus-404015.employee_data.departments`
```

[image: Second Image]

Comment: Is that last space actually there? "seraphic-plexus-404015.employee_data.departments "  <> "seraphic-plexus-404015.employee_data.departments" . Looks like it is because the first query works. I'd strongly recommend against having whitespace characters in table names.

Comment: Have you set a default region?

Comment: Ok, let me check that real quick, but i doubt it

Comment: It wasn't the whitespace, please how do I set default location, location of the dataset says US though, is that not correct? @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8697513/deeksha

Comment: In the console, go to Query settings > Advanced options > Automatic location set up